# How to pass data from one jbehave story file to another jbehave story file?

Tags: jbehave

I wish to transfer data from one jbehave story file to another jbehave story file.

I have already tried GivenStories syntax but that does not work for me.

Scenario 1 : Create an application

Given I login
Then I enter Amount
Then I enter Percentage

... Then pass parameters as global variables to a sub story

Continue with the original story

Parameters can be passed as global variables

Expected Results are The execution of the parent story should continue in the same session while calling the child story in between the story file

Answer (score 0):

Passing parameters or any other kind of data from one scenario to another is not a good practice. All scenario must be stand alone and should not rely on external data; to be predictive and reproducible.

Then... Like you said, to execute sub stories, you can use `GivenStories:` keyword.
Simplest way to pass any data between story, is to store it in memory.

```java
@Autowired //This object must be unique between all your stories
private Map<Object, Object> dataHolder;

@When("I enter Amount=$value")
public void enterAmount(Integer value){
  dataHolder.put("amount", value);
  //... the rest of your code
}

@Then("I do something with my parameters")
public void doSomething(){
  Integer amount = (Integer) dataHolder.get("amount");
  //... do anything you need with your parameters
}
```

You don't need the parameters for your next scenario, simply clean your dataHolder. You want to keep the same parameters, leave it as it is.